# A formula to average data from the last month

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a formula that will give an average of the numbers from column 'D' of 'TEST SHEET' into another Tab. That is easy enough, but I only want to use the data from the last 30 days.

I've been trying to create a formula, but I am new to these things and have only received error messages.

[TEST SHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuoVH.png)

Comment: "I've been trying to create a formula, but I am new to these things and have only received error messages." Please show the formula you have found so far (even though it doesn't work) and the error message.

Comment: =AVERAGEIF('Test sheet'!$A:$D (=>)Today(-(30)'test sheet'!$A:$D,4))

Comment: Ok, but don't provide these details in comments; instead, edit your question to include them. This way, everybody will see them. Keep in mind that not everybody checks the comments. And please do it even if in the meanwhile somebody has already solved your problem, so that your question can be more useful to other people who find it. And if an answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick on its left. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF('TEST SHEET'!A3:A,">"&today()-30,'TEST SHEET'!D3:D)
```

To get average for the days between last 60 and last 30 days ago, try the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('TEST SHEET'!D3:D,'TEST SHEET'!A3:A,">"&today()-60,'TEST SHEET'!A3:A,"<"&today()-30)
```

Comment: what if i wanted it to only search for between 60 and 30 days ago?